# Python copy file with Fabric - Windows to Debian

Tags: python, python-2.7, move, fabric

I am trying to use Python Fabric to copy a file from Windows to a debian system.

SOURCE: The Windows folder is `C:\Users\UserN\Downloads contains the file test_celsius.out`.

DESTINATION: The Debian folder is `/mnt/Reado/RoTempValC`.

I can move other files from the SOURCE to the DESTINATION using WinSCP. However, I need to use Fabric to move this particular file.

I can use Fabric to change into this directory and list its current contents:

```
ls /mnt/Reado/RoTempValC
```

**Here is what I have tried** - in a Fabric task named `move()` I have this

```
run('mv C:\Users\UserN\Downloads\test_celsius.out /mnt/Reado/RoTempValC')
```

Now, here is the output:

```
.
.
.
.
[10.10..] Executing task 'move'
[10.10..] run: mv C:\Users\UserN\Downloads\test_celsius.out /mnt/Reado/RoTempValC
[10.10..] out: mv: rename C:/Users/UserN/Downloads/test_celsius.out to /mnt/Reado/RoTempValC/test_celsius.out: No such file or directory
[10.10..] out: 

Disconnecting from 10.10.. done.

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: mv C:/Users/UserN/Downloads/test_celsius.out /mnt/Reado/RoTempValC
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "mv C:/Users/UserN/Downloads/test_celsius.out /mnt/Reado/RoTempValC"

Aborting.
```

I am not sure why it is doing this. I can correctly list the contents of the directory in Debian by using the `ls` command above.

Is there a way to copy this file?

**EDIT:**

Additional Information:

1. I am running the above `fab move` command from the Windows command
   prompt.
2. I opened the command prompt and typed `cd Python27\SGTemp`
   since this is where the `fabfile.py` is located.
3. Then I ran `fab move`.

**EDIT 2:**

I replaced `/mnt/Reado/RoTempVal` by `/mnt/Reado/RoTempValC/` but got the same output as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [fabric.operations.put(*args, **kwargs)](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put):

```
put('C:\Users\UserN\Downloads\test_celsius.out', '/mnt/Reado/RoTempValC')
```